My Selenium seesion using python is not able to click on a button
I am new to Selenium, and I am trying to search for my Linkedin profile and let me get on to the profile and allow me to click on the sign in button.
This is the code (a part of it is from chatgpt):
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Maximize the browser window
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Open Google
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    print("Opened Google.")

    # Locate the search bar and search for"my name Linkedin"
    element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
    element.clear()
    element.send_keys("my name Linkedin")
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    print("Searched for 'my name Linkedin'.")

    # Wait for the search results to appear and click the LinkedIn link
    linkedin_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'linkedin.com')]"))
    )
    linkedin_link.click()
    print("Clicked on LinkedIn link.")

    # Wait for the LinkedIn page to load and click the sign-in button
    sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'sign-in-modal__outlet-btn cursor-pointer btn-md btn-primary')]"))
    )
    sign_in_button.click()
    print("Clicked on 'Sign in' button.")

    # Verify the sign-in button is clicked by checking for the sign-in page elements
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
    )
    print("Sign-in page loaded successfully.")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
finally:
    # Wait for a while to see the result before quitting
    time.sleep(40)
    driver.quit()

Another way, I tried was very basic, but that didn't work as well(wrote by me based on whatever I understood).
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
# to locate any element by its class name on the webpage
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"gLFyf")
# to clear ant already present text
element.clear() 
#search for something on the search bar of the google webpage
element.send_keys("my name Linkedin")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"VuuXrf")
element.click()
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"sign-in-modal__outlet-btn cursor-pointer btn-md btn-primary")
element.click()
# element                           
time.sleep(40)
driver.quit()

Can anyone just tell me the mistakes in the code?
I was trying to make the Selenium session click on the sign in button on Linkedin , but it won't do it

Check the working code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
# Click on Accept all cookies
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']").click()
el = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"gLFyf")
el.send_keys("my name Linkedin")
el.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"VuuXrf").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Sign in']").click()
time.sleep(15)
driver.quit()

Issues in your code:

As soon as you launch google via selenium, it opens in a clean browser profile(similar to incognito mode). You will notice a cookie pop-up appears. You need to get rid of it before proceeding with further actions.

Below code is incorrect. You cannot use CLASS_NAME locator strategy when there are multiple classes.
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"sign-in-modal__outlet-btn cursor-pointer btn-md btn-primary")



Suggestions:

Use selenium's waits to effectively locate elements. You can use implicit or explicit waits. My preferred waits are explicit waits. I have used implicit wait in my answer.

You don't have to store the element in a variable always. Store it in a variable only if you want to use it more than once. For example, change below code,
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"VuuXrf")
element.click()

to,
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"VuuXrf").click()       




Your solution did not work for me. When I commented out driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']").click(), it was able to search and click the first LinkedIn button, but it still couldn't click the sign-in button. I also tried running the code with an actual person's name, but it still couldn't click the sign-in button. When searching for just "LinkedIn," it worked and clicked the sign-in button. Thanks for answering , will try to find other solutions
